# How to pass a different shade of color to a Component using React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following element:

```
<AppBar color="secondary">
  <Toolbar>
    ...
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

wrapped inside a ThemeProvider of:

```
palette: {
  primary: blue,
  secondary: blueGrey
}
```

The AppBar is now colored with `blueGrey` as expected. Although, I want the AppBar to be with a shade. How do I set the shade of the AppBar color to be 900 (which is `#263238`)?

TL;DR - Looking for a way to do:

```
<AppBar color="secondary" shade="dark">
```

Comment: So to clarify, you want hold the secondary color `blueGrey` and create some way of adding a shade by a new prop?

Comment: yes, I want to keep my secondary as blueGrey, without adding a new palette.

Comment: Have you tried to extend your existing palette to support dark and light alternatives in the secondary section? As shown [in the official color tool](https://material-ui.com/customization/color/#official-color-tool)

Comment: @minus.273 I don't see any reason to add a new palette when I do have the color I want which is `secondary[900 / secondary.dark`. I'm not sure how to be clearer in my intention.

Comment: You are not adding a new palette. On the palette that you have, you are simply modifying the secondary attribute of your own existing palette. Your main in the secondary will be `blueGray` and the light or dark attribute will have whatever else you need as a shade.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any way to do this via props, but you can use `withStyles` to override the [background color](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.6.1/packages/material-ui/src/AppBar/AppBar.js#L65) as shown below.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import blue from "@material-ui/core/colors/blue";
import blueGrey from "@material-ui/core/colors/blueGrey";
import {
  ThemeProvider,
  createMuiTheme,
  withStyles
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: blue,
    secondary: blueGrey
  }
});
const DarkAppBar = withStyles(theme => ({
  colorSecondary: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark
  }
}))(AppBar);
function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <DarkAppBar color="secondary">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6">My AppBar</Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </DarkAppBar>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit dark AppBar]

Comment: I'm using Typescript, so is there a cleaner way of this syntax?

Comment: See https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#using-createstyles-to-defeat-type-widening.